# Is there a way to force hardcoded styling in HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, css

I know this sounds like the exact opposite of what we're trying to achieve when it comes to a responsive web but, I have a python script that is popping out a github flavored HTML sheet and I want to export the article tag and all of its rendered styling so I can post it like a HTML based screenshot on another page (my computer science class discussion forums for this example).

For now I am converting the styling by hand through chrome's developer tools but I would like an automated way to apply all of the styling to hardcode the elements so none of my styling leaks out to the rest of the webpage and I'm able to present a solid piece of HTML that displays itself as well as an image would.

I attempted to make a nested for loop that would apply all of the applied stylings to the element but there were a lot of errors in that implementation because of different types of tags.

If there is an easy way to do this I would love to know about it. Even if it's a web service that I have to paste my html into to get the hardcoded result.

I love being able to prepare my responses and I love the type of styling GitHub flavoring has. I would just really like to keep it in HTML instead of posting screenshots everywhere.

One last note, no iframes or just linking to another page to view the content.

Comment: If not quite sure what you're asking. If you want a tool to tidy up the formatting of some HTML code, I use http://jsfiddle.net. Paste it in the HTML window and click the 'Tidy up' button at the top.

Comment: Tried it but nope. Basically I need to put all of the styling in the `<div style="background:black;"></div>` area because my school strips out style tags but allows hardcoded html styling. So pretty much remove all of the style tags but keep the styling applied to the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing a `Blob` , `URL.createObjectURL` to save , "export" `html` fragment

```
var elem = $("article");

var styles = elem.css(["width", "height" /* , additional style properties */ ]);

elem.attr("style", function(i, style) {
  return $.map(styles, function(val, key) {
    return return key + ":" + val + ";"
  }).join();
});

var blob = new Blob([elem[0].outerHTML], {"type":"text/html"});

var objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// do stuff with `objUrl`
// window.open(objUrl);
```